# Iterate with last element repeated as first in next iteration

Tags: python, list, nested, iteration

I have some list with objects looks like:

```
oldList=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,...]
```

what I need is to create a new list with nested list items which will look like this:

```
newList=[[a,b,c,d],[d,e,f,g],[g,h,i,j]...]
```

or simply spoken - last element from previous nested is first element in next new nested list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways of doing it is

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
>>> [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(l),3)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], ['j']]
```

Here :

- `l[i:i+4]` implies that we print a chunk of 4 values starting from position `i`
- `range(0,len(l),3)` implies that we traverse the length of the list by taking three jumps

So the basic working of this is that, we are taking a chunk of 3 elements from the list, but we are modifying the slice length so that it includes an additional element. In this way, we can have a list of *4* elements.

*Small Note* - The initialization `oldList=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,...]` is invalid unless `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,etc are previously defined. You were perhaps looking for `oldList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']`

Alternatively, if you wanted a solution which would split into *even* sized chunks only, then you could try this code :-

```
>>> [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(l)-len(l)%4,3)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Comment: Sorry, me again, can you suggest me some source to learn pythonic way to create code?

Comment: Lol! Go through the official tutorial once. Then try to solve a few puzzles. Check out the best answers for them online... You will become pythonic eventually!

Comment: Tnx again for your time  :)